# Paypal - BMCreateButton - Subtotal amount is not valid

Tags: paypal

I've started to receive the error:

```
Ack: Failure
Correlation ID: d1ed16a437fc9
Version: 85
Error Number: 13117
Short Message: Invalid Argument
Long Message: Subtotal amount is not valid.
```

When making a BMCreateButton request, the script has been working fine, can anyone see what's wrong with the request below? Also I can't find a spec anywhere that states what the format for the subtotal amount should be.

```
METHOD=BMCreateButton
&VERSION=85
&PWD=xxxxxxx
&USER=xxxxxxx
&SIGNATURE=xxxxxxx
&BUTTONCODE=TOKEN
&BUTTONTYPE=PAYMENT
&L_BUTTONVAR0=address1=11 The Oaks
&L_BUTTONVAR1=address2=
&L_BUTTONVAR2=address_override=true
&L_BUTTONVAR3=billing_address1=11 The Oaks
&L_BUTTONVAR4=billing_address2=
&L_BUTTONVAR5=billing_city=Fleet
&L_BUTTONVAR6=billing_country=UNITED KINGDOM
&L_BUTTONVAR7=billing_first_name=Victoria
&L_BUTTONVAR8=billing_last_name=Fry
&L_BUTTONVAR9=billing_state=Hampshire
&L_BUTTONVAR10=billing_zip=GU51 4HQ
&L_BUTTONVAR11=business=XDQD9TZGYQ9YY
&L_BUTTONVAR12=buyer_email=xxxxxxx
&L_BUTTONVAR13=cancel_return=xxxxxxx
&L_BUTTONVAR14=city=Fleet
&L_BUTTONVAR15=country=UNITED KINGDOM
&L_BUTTONVAR16=currency_code=GBP
&L_BUTTONVAR17=first_name=Victoria
&L_BUTTONVAR18=invoice=8132
&L_BUTTONVAR19=last_name=Fry
&L_BUTTONVAR20=lc=US
&L_BUTTONVAR21=notify_url=xxxxxxx
&L_BUTTONVAR22=paymentaction=sale
&L_BUTTONVAR23=return=xxxxxxx
&L_BUTTONVAR24=shipping=0
&L_BUTTONVAR25=state=Hampshire
&L_BUTTONVAR26=subtotal=65
&L_BUTTONVAR27=zip=GU51 4HQ
```

The values are php url encoded.

Many thanks for any advise.

Comment: Well it turns out it wasn't the request that was causing the problem but the endpoint https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp wasn't responding. But it is now so the request works, but I still get the error if I run it through this: http://quar.me/paypal/api/nvp/bmcreatebutton so I've no idea what's going on!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this error by adding a subtotal item ala:

```
"L_BUTTONVAR3" :"subtotal=10.99"
```